# My app is exiting with an error message when I'm trying to pass the 2nd intent even after using Async task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

While passing the second `intent` from main screen in `Logcat` it's showing

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d09b20)
06-14 11:16:24.513 4507-4507/com.infinity.wall_to_paper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.infinity.wall_to_paper, PID: 4507
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infinity.wall_to_paper/com.infinity.wall_to_paper.Settings}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                              at com.infinity.wall_to_paper.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:22)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                              at com.infinity.wall_to_paper.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:22) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
                                                                              at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
                                                                              at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
                                                                              at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
                                                                              at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                              at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3554)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:470)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                              at com.infinity.wall_to_paper.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:22) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Program is :

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

ImageView show_cat,settings;
     @Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //MainScreen
    show_cat=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.show_cat);
    settings=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.setting_show_fragment);
   }

    public void showCat(View view){

     //on click method
     new MyCustomAsyncTask(this).execute();
}

public void showSettings(View view){
    //on click method
    Intent i= new Intent(this, Settings.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }}
```

And I am using `Async task`:

public class MyCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
    private Context context;

```
public MyCustomAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context=context;

}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // write show progress Dialog code here
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // write service code here
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Categories.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);

}
    }
```

Layout File for Categories is :

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_category">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/sports"
        android:src="@drawable/sports"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sports"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nature"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nature"
        android:onClick="openSports" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/love"
        android:src="@drawable/love"
        android:layout_above="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sports"
        android:contentDescription="@string/love"
        android:onClick="openLove" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/movies"
        android:src="@drawable/movies"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nature"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nature"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/nature"
        android:contentDescription="@string/movies"
        android:onClick="openMovies" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/superhero"
        android:src="@drawable/superhero"
        android:layout_below="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/movies"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/movies"
        android:contentDescription="@string/superhero"
        android:onClick="openSuperhero" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/cartoons"
        android:src="@drawable/cartoons"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cartoons"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="openCartoons" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/artistic"
        android:src="@drawable/artistic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nature"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/animals"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/animals"
        android:contentDescription="@string/artistic"
        android:onClick="openArtistic" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:id="@+id/animals"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:src="@drawable/animals"
        android:layout_above="@+id/artistic"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sports"
        android:contentDescription="@string/animals"
        android:onClick="openAnimals" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/vehicles"
        android:src="@drawable/vehicles"
        android:layout_below="@+id/artistic"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/artistic"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/artistic"
        android:contentDescription="@string/vehicles"
        android:onClick="openVehicles" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/nature"
        android:src="@drawable/nature"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cartoons"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/cartoons"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nature"
        android:onClick="openNature" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/back_to_main"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back_going"
        android:background="@drawable/back_going"
        android:onClick="onClickBack"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sports"
        android:layout_marginRight="220dp" />
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file for Categories.class?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the rest of the inflate exception

Comment: Do you really think it's a good idea to be passing an Activity context to an AsyncTask, this is asking for a memory leak?

Comment: @DeepakSingh Sir I've added the layout file

Comment: @cricket_007 Sir I've added the complete error message

Comment: @MarkKeen I don't know Sir so please help me to sort out the error

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`... There is some image or resource that is being loaded in this layout that is too large

Comment: Also, the error is in `Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:22)`, which you have not even shown that code. Please refer [What is a stacktrace, and how can I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Image you are setting as background in 
drawable/wallpaper_category is causing Out of Memory exception.

Remove line number 2 of layout file and it will run without any crash.

You need to use Glide or Picasso to load images efficiently.